# Threading with pytube while searching

Tags: python, multithreading, pytube

This is my code, I'm trying to download a playlist from youtube.In order to prevent the app from taking  too long, I use threading. But it is taking too long and I'm literally not getting any reaction form the window. Simply it's not working.Does anyone know what the problem is? (Note that I am new to python).Thank you in advance.
Here is my code:

```
def playlist_search():


global pl 
    url = playlist_link_entry.get()
    try:
        #Create a PlayList object
        #Downloading is gonna happen with pytube 
        pl = Playlist(url)
    except:
        messagebox.showerror("Error","Either link is not functioning or connection broken".title())
    
    #Gotta get the links to every single video
    #We name it 'video_link_playlist'
    #for that specific url we do our shit(get itag, size and ... thats exactly our previous code)
    #We map the playlist_actual_search to pl.video_urls

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(playlist_actual_search, pl.video_urls)
```

We create this function to do the search concurrently

```
def playlist_actual_search(pl_link):


    #Saving All Links to a list to use it later
    playlist_link_list.append(pl_link)

    #Getting itag number is gonna happen with pafy
    #Create a pafy object
    video = pafy.new(pl_link)

    #Get all streams from youtube
    streams = video.allstreams

    #Create a YouTube object to get every video individually
    yt = YouTube(pl_link)

    #Add yt to the yt.list
    yt_list.append(yt)

    #Get those streams that are normal(addaptive)
    for stream in streams:
        if "normal" in str(stream):
            playlist_normal_stream_list.append(stream)

        #Get itag value of the addaptive video
        for normal_stream in playlist_normal_stream_list:
            
            if "720" in str(normal_stream):
                itag720 = normal_stream.itag
                playlist_itag_value_dic["itag720"] = itag720
                normal_stream = yt.streams.get_by_itag(itag720)
                playlist720_video_size += normal_stream.filesize_approx

            if "480" in str(normal_stream):
                itag480 = normal_stream.itag
                playlist_itag_value_dic["itag480"] = itag480
                normal_stream = yt.streams.get_by_itag(itag480)
                playlist480_video_size += normal_stream.filesize_approx

            if "360" in str(normal_stream):
                itag360 = normal_stream.itag
                playlist_itag_value_dic["itag360"] = itag360
                normal_stream = yt.streams.get_by_itag(itag360)
                playlist360_video_size += normal_stream.filesize_approx
```

Comment: i think you forgot to provide the number of threads at `with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:`  try providing the thread number `max_workers =10` then try again.

Comment: I have done that but still not working!@Abhishek